# Verificar duas negações em uma expressão do if

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Eu estou colocando isso:

```
if(!teste.trim().equals("") || (!(teste == null))){
    // ...faz algo sem NullPointerException...
}
```

Mas a segunda cláusula não está funcionando, a que testa se não é `null`.

Não sei o que faço.

Posteriormente consegui fazer com dois `if`s:

```
if (sampleString != null){
    if(!sampleString.tri‌​m().equals("")){
```

Mas gostaria de saber porque a primeira forma não funciona.

Comment: Antes de vc falar isso eu fiz.
Consegui com dois ifs: if (sampleString != null){
        if(!sampleString.trim().equals("")){

Comment: renan porque vc apagou seu comentário?

Comment: renan me explica porque esse && e não ||? Porque a variável pode ser null ou blank " "

Comment: porque eu preciso verificar se primeiro é nulo?

Comment: Porque comentários são descartáveis :D Mas respondendo: da forma como está seu código, `!teste.trim().equals("")` já teria lançado uma exceção se "teste" fosse nulo, logo não faz sentido checar por `null` após verificar se é vazia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu problema está em interpretar a ordem com que as subexpressões são avaliadas.

Se você tem uma expressão `if (a || b)`, ela será avaliada assim:

- Se `a` for verdadeiro, então toda a expressão será verdadeira e o `b` não será avaliado.
- Se `a` for verdadeiro, então o `b` será avaliado e a expressão será verdadeira se `b` for verdadeiro ou falsa se `b` for falso.

De forma semelhante, uma expressão `if (a && b)` será avaliada assim:

- Se `a` for falso, então toda a expressão será falsa e o `b` não será avaliado.
- Se `a` for verdadeiro, então o `b` será avaliado e a expressão será verdadeira se `b` for verdadeiro ou falsa se `b` for falso.

Observe que no caso do `||`, que a primeira subexpressão ser verdadeira significa que a segunda não será avaliada, então quaisquer efeitos colaterais que a segunda subexpressão pudesse produzir ao ser avaliada (incluindo um `NullPointerException`) não acontecerão se a primeira subexpressão for verdadeira. Isso também significa que fazer um `if (a || b) {` pode dar um efeito totalmente diferente de fazer `if (b || a) {`.

No seu caso, para evitar um `NullPointerException`, faz sentido você primeiro verificar se um objeto é ou não `null` para depois tentar usá-lo (o contrário não faz sentido). E isso é conseguido ao inverter a ordem das subexpressões:

```
if((!(teste == null)) || !teste.trim().equals("")){
    // ...faz algo sem NullPointerException...
}
```

O motivo é que se `teste` for `null`, então tentar avaliar `teste.trim()` causa um `NullPointerException`, e é por isso que a expressão `!(teste == null)` tem que estar antes do `!teste.trim()`.

Entretanto, ainda assim o código não funcionará. Ainda há mais um erro conceitual, que pode ser facilmente revelado ao tentar simplificá-lo. Primeiramente uma expressão `!(a == b)` é equivalente a `a != b`, e portanto `(!(teste == null))` é o mesmo que `teste != null`. Assim sendo sua expressão ficaria assim:

```
if (teste != null || !teste.trim().equals("")) {
    // ...faz algo sem NullPointerException...
}
```

Sabendo-se que a segunda subexpressão só será avaliada quando a primeira for falsa, questiona-se: Em que circustância a primeira subexpressão é falsa? A resposta é que isso ocorre quando `teste` for `null`, e portanto a segunda subexpressão só será avaliada quando `teste` for `null`. Entretanto, se `teste` for `null`, então você vai garantidamente ter um `NullPointerException` ao avaliar a segunda subexpressão!

O que você quer na verdade é entrar dentro do `if` se `teste` não for `null` **E** nem for vazio. Ou seja, era para usar o `&&` ao invés do `||`:

```
if (teste != null && !teste.trim().equals("")) {
    // ...faz algo sem NullPointerException...
}
```

Observe que isso é equivalente a solução de contorno que você achou:

```
if (sampleString != null) {
    if (!sampleString.tri‌​m().equals("")) {
        // ...faz algo sem NullPointerException...
    }
}
```

Pois o que esses dois `if`s fazem é exatamente o mesmo que o `&&` faria: Só vai entrar quando as duas expressões forem verdadeiras sendo que a segunda só será avaliada se a primeira for verdadeira. Aliás, uma forma de simplificar `if (a) { if (b) { ... }}` é exatamente transformá-lo em `if (a && b) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4):

Isso é básico mas pode ser complicado para quem está iniciando. Antes de invocar um método em qualquer instância do objeto sempre pergunte se é nulo:

```
teste == null 
teste != null
```

Se você tentar invocar um método em uma váriavel de um tipo de classe qualquer atribuída com `null` vai dar de cara com `NullPointerException`:

```
String teste = null;
teste.isEmpty();      //Vai dar NullPointerException
```

Então no seu caso seria assim:

```
if (!(teste == null) && !(teste.trim().equals("")) {
    // ...faz algo sem nullpointerException...
}
```

Ou mais simples:

```
if (teste != null && !teste.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // ...faz algo sem nullpointerException...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O erro está na comparação da condição. Na verdade você tem que verificar primeiramente se a váriável `teste` está nula, para depois fazer qualquer tipo de verificação.

```
!(teste == null)
```

Você tem que fazer desta maneira para verificar se o valor é nulo:

```
teste != null
```

**Explicando por que a primeira forma não funciona...**

Digamos que teste não seja `null`.

A primeira expressão que é validada é a que está dentro dos parênteses, portanto `teste == null` retorna false. O que o ! faz é inverter o resultado, portanto retorna true.

O que acontece é que você estava validando corretamente e depois pegando o resultado contrário.

Comment: ? Mas não era bem isso que queria...Mas valeu por tentar me ajudar. :)

Comment: O que é que você queria então? :0

Comment: a culpa foi minha a pergunta está meio mal feita. 
Isso que eu queria:      if (!(sampleString == null) && !sampleString.trim().equals("")){

Comment: Ué. Mas a solução é a mesma... `sampleString != null`.

Comment: é sim. relaxe. :)